# Ways of definging metadata for spring roo

Tags: java, metadata, spring-roo

is there any other way of supplying Roo with metadata ? Other than from commandline ?

Wouldn't this make much more sense ? This would be the core metadata definition for the entire application and developer would just modify that in the course of development.

```
<entity name="CustomerAccount" local-service="true" remote-service="false">

    <!-- PK fields -->

    <column name="customerAccountId" type="long" primary="true" id-type="class" id-param="com.liferay.counter.service.persistence.IDGenerator" />

    <!-- Audit fields -->

    <column name="companyId"    type="long" />
    <column name="userId"       type="long" />
    <column name="userName"     type="String" />
    <column name="createDate"   type="Date" />
    <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date" />
    <column name="emailAddress" type="String" />

    <!-- Other fields -->

    <column name="balance" type="Integer" />

    <!--  One 2 Many -->

    <column name="customerOrders" type="Collection"
        entity="Order"
        mapping-key="customerAccountId" 
    />

    <!-- Order -->

    <order by="asc">
        <order-column name="emailAddress" />
    </order>

    <!-- Finder methods -->

    <finder name="U_EA" return-type="CustomerAccount">
        <finder-column name="userId" />
        <finder-column name="emailAddress" />
    </finder>

</entity>

<entity name="TranslatorAccount" local-service="true" remote-service="false">

    <!-- PK fields -->

    <column name="translatorAccountId" type="long" primary="true" />

    <!-- Audit fields -->

    <column name="companyId"    type="long" />
    <column name="userId"       type="long" />
    <column name="userName"     type="String" />
    <column name="createDate"   type="Date" />
    <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date" />
    <column name="emailAddress" type="String" />

    <!-- Other fields -->

    <column name="reputation" type="Integer" />

    <!--  Many 2 Many -->
    <!--

    <column name="translatorOrders" type="Collection"
        entity="Order"
        mapping-table="TranslatorAccount_Order"
    />


    -->

                <!--  One 2 Many -->

    <column name="bids" type="Collection"
        entity="Bid"
        mapping-key="translatorAccountId" 
    />


    <!-- Order -->

    <order by="asc">
        <order-column name="emailAddress" />
    </order>

    <!-- Finder methods -->

    <finder name="U_EA" return-type="TranslatorAccount">
        <finder-column name="userId" />
        <finder-column name="emailAddress" />
    </finder>

</entity>

<entity name="Order" uuid="true" local-service="true" remote-service="true">

    <!-- PK fields -->

    <column name="orderId" type="long" primary="true" />

    <!-- FK fields -->

    <column name="customerAccountId" type="long"/>      

            <!--  One 2 Many -->

    <column name="bids" type="Collection"
        entity="Bid"
        mapping-key="orderId" 
    />


    <!-- Audit fields -->

    <column name="companyId" type="long" />
    <column name="userId" type="long" />
    <column name="createDate" type="Date" />
    <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date" />

    <!-- Group instance -->

    <column name="groupId" type="long" />

    <!-- Other fields -->

    <column name="languageFrom"      type="String" />
    <column name="languageTo"        type="String" />
    <column name="description"       type="String" />
    <column name="specialization"    type="String" />
    <column name="significanceLevel" type="Integer" />
    <column name="comment"           type="String" />       
    <column name="fileEntryIds"      type="String" />       
    <column name="deadLine"          type="Date" />

    <!-- Bid related -->
    <column name="currentPrice"     type="Integer" />
    <column name="maxValue"         type="Integer" />
    <column name="minValue"         type="Integer" />
    <column name="bidsCount"        type="Integer" />



    <order by="asc">
        <order-column name="createDate" />
    </order>

    <!-- Finder methods -->

    <finder name="languageFrom" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="languageFrom" />
    </finder>

    <finder name="languageTo" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="languageTo" />
    </finder>

        <finder name="U_LFT" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="languageFrom" />
        <finder-column name="languageTo" />
    </finder>

    <finder name="significanceLevel" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="significanceLevel" />
    </finder>

    <finder name="createDate" return-type="Collection" >
        <finder-column name="createDate" />
    </finder>

    <finder name="orderIdOlderThanNow" return-type="Collection" >
        <finder-column name="createDate" comparator=">"/>
    </finder>

    <!-- References -->

    <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.asset" entity="AssetEntry" />
    <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.asset" entity="AssetTag" />
    <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.ratings" entity="RatingsStats" />
    <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.social" entity="SocialActivity" />
    <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.social" entity="SocialEquityLog" />

</entity>


<entity name="Bid" local-service="true" remote-service="true">

    <!-- PK fields -->

    <column name="bidId"                type="long" primary="true" />
    <column name="orderId"              type="long" />
    <column name="translatorAccountId"  type="long" />

    <!-- Audit fields -->

    <column name="userId"               type="long" />
    <column name="createDate"           type="String" />

    <!-- Other fields -->

    <column name="bidValue"             type="Integer" />
    <column name="nth"                  type="Integer" />
    <column name="resultPrice"          type="Integer" />

    <!-- Order -->

    <order by="asc">
        <order-column name="createDate" />
    </order>

    <finder name="orderId" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="orderId" />
    </finder>

</entity>

<entity name="OrderState" local-service="true" >

    <!-- PK fields -->

    <column name="orderId" type="long" primary="true" />
    <column name="orderState" type="Integer" />
    <column name="stateCycle" type="Integer" />

</entity>

<entity name="Utils" local-service="false" remote-service="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever considered the **script** command, which accepts a simple text file input.

Comment: Yes, every shell should have that. But still, using entities definition (like some other source code generators do), I can change and entity and run source code generator to reflect the changes. Can I do this with series of commands in the script ? Is there a command that removes everything and I run the modified script ?

Comment: I mean this is what I don't like about roo. This fancy shell. Xml metadata definition is much more effective and natural way ... At least you see the entire domain model and you can contemplate what to do next.